# ASP.Net MVC 5 routing with culture url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I followed [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) guide and it works fine with my language support. Url's such as 
http://domain.com:33982/en-us/Test works great.

However my issue is that I want it to work with 
http://domain.com:33982/Test as well. I can't figure it out how to route it without the culture in the link...
My routes in the RouteConfig.cs

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
name: "MissingCulture",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Test", action = "PageMissing", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't work. When I go to /Test to just redirects me to the default Home/Index.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what if you dont set a default for culture on the Default route?

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the first and second route both match. The optional parameters cause the application to choose the first one that matches: so the first one always gets picked.

Try this:

```
        routes.MapRoute( name: "DefaultWithCulture"
                       , url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
                       , defaults: new { culture = "en-us", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                       , constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute( name: "Default"
                       , url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
                       , defaults: new { culture = "xx-xx", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It works over here for (retulting culture behind them):

```
http://host/ (en-us)
http://host/Home/Index (xx-xx)
http://host/zh-cn/Home/Index (zh-cn)
```

Comment: Really do not want to add Test (a.k.a name of all my controllers) to the route.cs. Really want to use the {controller} in that case.

Comment: Just an example to show you the matching engine is the problem. You have to do something to make the routing engine make the right decision. Updated example.

Comment: I see your example, is that any way not to have the DefaultCulture there? I really want it to work with domain.com/{controller} and not want it to redirect to error-page just because the culture isn't there...

Comment: I assume the constraint should be: constraints: new {  culture="[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}"  } becuase the other one is not working (compile error). However it still doesn't seem to work. /en/Test doesn't work. The only way to get it working now is by: "Test/Index", not even /Test/ work.

Comment: And if you use en-us?

Comment: @PatrickHofman you may want to see mostafa kazemi answer: he was trying to comment on your answer regarding the `constraints`, but didn't had enough reputation for that.